# Oracle - Can't Use DB Link 11.2.0.1.0 to 11.2.0.4.0?

Tags: oracle, dblink

I want to use DB Link 11.2.0.1.0 to 11.2.0.4.0.

So, I create DB Link in 11.2.0.1.0, and send SELECT query to 11.2.0.4.0.

But error occured.

```
14:35:07 Error: ORA-00600: internal error code arguments: [2252], [9170], [2244904288], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Can't use DB Link that 11.2.0.1.0 to 11.2.0.4.0?

Or is there any way to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have these two Oracle database version to try myself, but - they are **so close** (differ on the 3rd decimal) that I doubt it won't work.

On the other hand, ORA-00600 is usually *bad news* as it represents Oracle **bug** you should report to Oracle Support. However, as 11g is out of support, you might be out of luck.

---

Did you correctly create database link? Oracle kind of *fools* us when we create database link which is actually invalid, but it (Oracle) reports that it is *successfully* created.

This is Oracle 11.2.0.4.0; non-existent user doesn't exist (of course it doesn't), but - database link is created:

```
SQL> create database link dbl_test
  2    connect to non_existent_user
  3    identified by you_must_be_kidding
  4    using 'orcl';

Database link created.
```

Can I use it? Of course not:

```
SQL> select * from dual@dbl_test;
select * from dual@dbl_test
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

So, maybe you did something *foolish* as I did, thinking that everything went OK while it didn't.

I'd suggest you to drop it (the link) and create it once again, carefully specifying all relevant information.